# Writing to and retrieving the latest entry from dynamoDB using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on an AWS lambda function which has to write and retrieve values from a DynamoDB table.

- The only purpose of this table is to keep a list of timestamps.
- Each time the lambda runs, it would check whether a value v exist in the dynamo DB table.
- If it exists in the dynamo table, the lambda function will exit.
- If it doesn't exist in the dynamo DB table, the lambda will insert the item into the dynamo DB table and then continue with the rest of the function.

Given in the image is a sample table I have created on dynamoDB. I am trying to use AWS boto3 on Python. My assumption was that the table entries are in a JSON structure like this and `tStamp[0]` would be the last entry in the table.

```
{
  "tStamp": [ "1566132618","1566132618","1566132628","1566132518","1566132418"]
}
```

However the following code is giving error.

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
response = client.get_item(TableName='instatable',Key={
    "tStamp"[0]
})
```

Appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction. I am a noob in both non-relational DBs and AWS.

[image]

Comment: no, each entry is a different row in database, and these is not way to get the latest one without doing a scan (DON'T DO IT). you can check if some item exists or not, but you can not get the latest one.

Comment: What problem are you solving? Do you need a guard for your Lambda function? Have you tried to use [python-dynamodb-lock](https://pypi.org/project/python-dynamodb-lock)?

Comment: @bestwishes Checking whether an entry exist or not also is fine. I did some search and I couldn't make it work. Would it be possible with this dynamoidb structure I am using?

Comment: yes, Just do key="1566132618"